# User babylisscurl is repeatedly spamming this site

Tags: support, spam

There is a user "babylisscurl" who is repeatedly spamming this site. You guys should IP ban him or sometime. See [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=babylisscurl&User=266345&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) for proof.

Also, nuke all remaining accounts he / she has.

Answer (score 2):

Please use flags to communicate with moderators.

- If you think an answer is spam, flag it as such.
- If you think that there are a pattern of spam answers from one user, you *may* wish to use the **Other** flag type on one of that user’s posts to write a short message saying so. However, this should not be necessary: a repeated pattern of spamming from one user is already brought to the moderators’ attention automatically by the system.

Comment: Repeated offense might mean flags didn't work. If user suspects that, or for any other reason feels the need to bring issue to general public, meta post is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: Do not use any other flag for spam. The spam flag is special.  Other flags will slow down its removal.

Comment: Actually, its many users